# MySQL error: This type of clause previously parsed. (near SELECT)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to copy values from one table to another when some condition is passed. But i got following error in doing so..

> This type of clause previously parsed. (near SELECT)

```
SELECT prefKey FROM master 
 WHERE id=[SELECT broaderid FROM broader WHERE id=[SELECT id FROM master]];
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with your use of square brackets.

Comment: You are using same table in sub query but without alias :P

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use simple `JOIN` for that:

```
SELECT
    m.prefKey
FROM
    `master` m
    INNER JOIN broader b ON m.id = b.broaderid
```